# Parse RFC3339 timestamp in spark

Tags: csv, date, apache-spark, pyspark, simpledateformat

Spark's CSV `timestampFormat`:

> timestampFormat – sets the string that indicates a timestamp format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to timestamp type. If None is set, it uses the default value, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX.

[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) seems doesn't support RFC3339 well, which would look like `2017-11-27T07:10:07Z`.

How should I configure spark to parse this time format when reading a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark will do it for you automatically:

```
>>> df=spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("delimiter",",").csv("file:///temp/1.csv")
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- val: integer (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+-------------------+---+
|                 ts|val|
+-------------------+---+
|2017-11-27 08:10:07|  1|
|2017-11-28 09:08:08|  1|
|2017-11-30 00:59:59|  1|
+-------------------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that it's the `^M` line break that breaks the inferSchema.